How to Fetch Pool Keys in Solana After Detecting Pool Creation Signature?
I'm working on a Solana project where I need to track liquidity pool creation events triggered by specific programs. I’m able to detect these events by monitoring logs and looking for a unique "initialize2" signature, which indicates a pool creation. However, the logs do not include the actual pool public key, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to fetch the pool keys once I detect this signature.
Here’s a simplified version of my code for detecting the pool creation event:
const programId = new PublicKey("...");

connection.onLogs(
  programId,
  (logInfo) => {
    if (logInfo.logs.some(log => log.includes("initialize2"))) {
      console.log("Detected pool creation event.");
      // Need help fetching the pool key here
    }
  },
  "confirmed"
);

I’ve tried using getProgramAccounts to fetch recent accounts created by the program, filtering by quoteMint and account size, but it’s not always clear if I’m getting the correct pool keys associated with the detected "initialize2" event.
Given that I can detect the "initialize2" signature in the logs, how can I reliably fetch the associated pool key?

If you've got the signature, you're almost there! You just need to call get_transaction with that signature and then look through the account keys in the raydium instruction. I couldn't find an example of an initialize2 instruction, but if you can find an IDL or a library, you should be able to figure out which account corresponds to the pool key.
